# BlueMarble is appearing strange

Tags: gdal, wms, worldwind

I am fairly new to WorldWind and want to make WorldWind Server 1.5 server blue Marble Imagery to  worldwind 2.0. I am using **WMSLayerManager applet** to test my server.

Blue marble appears strange on worldwind 2.0. Please have a look at images.
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Here is run down of what I did. 
I have downloaded blueMarble data from NASA and ran following commands to convert pngs to gtifs.

```
gdal_translate -of gtiff -a_srs epsg:4326 -a_ullr -180 90 -90 0 -co tiled=yes -co compress=lzw world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.A1.png world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.A1.gtif

gdal_translate -of gtiff -a_srs epsg:4326 -a_ullr -180 0 -90 -90 -co tiled=yes -co compress=lzw world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.A2.png world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.A2.gtif

gdal_translate -of gtiff -a_srs epsg:4326 -a_ullr -90 90 0 0 -co tiled=yes -co compress=lzw world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.B1.png world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.B1.gtif

gdal_translate -of gtiff -a_srs epsg:4326 -a_ullr -90 0 0 -90 -co tiled=yes -co compress=lzw world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.B2.png world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.B2.gtif

gdal_translate -of gtiff -a_srs epsg:4326 -a_ullr 0 90 90 0 -co tiled=yes -co compress=lzw world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.C1 .png world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.C1 .gtif

gdal_translate -of gtiff -a_srs epsg:4326 -a_ullr 0 0 90 -90 -co tiled=yes -co compress=lzw world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.C2.png world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.C2.gtif

gdal_translate -of gtiff -a_srs epsg:4326 -a_ullr 90 90 180 0 -co tiled=yes -co compress=lzw world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.D1.png world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.D1.gtif

gdal_translate -of gtiff -a_srs epsg:4326 -a_ullr 90 0 180 -90 -co tiled=yes -co compress=lzw world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.D2.png world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.D2.gtif
```

Here is Gdal info of world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x21600.A1.gtif

```
D:\BM>gdalinfo world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x10800.gtif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: world.topo.bathy.200412.3x21600x10800.gtif
Size is 21600, 10800
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
DATUM["WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left ( 0.0, 0.0)
Lower Left ( 0.0,10800.0)
Upper Right (21600.0, 0.0)
Lower Right (21600.0,10800.0)
Center (10800.0, 5400.0)
Band 1 Block=21600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=21600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=21600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

finally I added it to config file like:

```
<mapsource name="bmng200401" title="BlueMarbleNG 01/2004">
     <description keywords="NASA; Blue Marble; Global Imagery: 2004">Nasa's BlueMarbleNG, 2004GTIF</description>
     <root-dir>c:\Data\BlueMarble</root-dir>
     <class>gov.nasa.worldwind.servers.wms.generators.BlueMarbleNG500MGenerator</class>
     <property name="BlueMarble500M.defaultTime" value="200412"/>
     <property name="BlueMarble500M.namingscheme.prefix" value="world.topo.bathy" />
     <property name="BlueMarble500M.namingscheme.suffix" value="gtif" />
     <property name="gov.nasa.worldwind.avkey.LastUpdateKey" value="2009-03-24 10:55:00" />
</mapsource>
```

Who is the causing the problem? Is it **WMSLayerManager **, WMS Server or most probably the wrong projection.
I have also posted the same on http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?45461-BlueMarble-Projection-problem

What I am doing wrong. Can anyone please help me out.